# Setting column order for CSVHelper

Tags: c#, csvhelper

I am using CSVMapper to output the objects within a dictionary:

```
        using (TextWriter writer = new StreamWriter($"somefile.csv"))
        {
            var csvDP = new CsvWriter(writer);
            csvDP.WriteHeader<NodeDPCount>();
            csvDP.NextRecord();
            foreach (NodeDPCount dpItem in dp.Values)
            {
                csvDP.WriteRecord(dpItem);
                csvDP.NextRecord();
            }
        }
```

It is a simple class with fields like ID, Name, Age, etc.

However, the output of the columns is in an order I do not like (e.g. ID is not first) and I want to specify which column is first, second, etc.

I believe I have to use the Mapping class, but from the documentation I cannot figure it out. I was hoping for something simple like an annotation to the class, but I guess not.

Can anyone help?

thanks.

Comment: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: I thought it irrelevant to include my class as it was a question about ordering. I can happily include it.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Take a look at the Mapping section of the website for `CSVHelper` (http://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/2.x/)

Specifically:

> When mapping by index you specify the index of the CSV column that that you want to use for that property

So you'll have to specify a mapping class for your `NodeDPCount` class, telling it which index to use for which records.

```
public sealed class MyNodeDPCountMap : CsvClassMap<NodeDPCount>
{
    public MyNodeDPCountMap()
    {
        Map( m => m.Id ).Index( 0 );
        Map( m => m.Name ).Index( 1 );
        // etc.
    }
}
```

For this to work, you'll need to register your map:

```
csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<MyNodeDPCountMap>();
```

Then it will know to use the map you've registered when interacting with the `NodeDPCount` class

Comment: thanks, I read that bit but didn't quite understand, but the register class  map ties it all together and it wasn't quite obvious from the v3 to do this. Thanks.

But I think annotations would make it a lot simpler and easier :)

Comment: I had to use `ClassMap<NodeDPCount>` instead of `CsvClassMap<NodeDPCount>`

Answer (score 9):

You can just use the Index attribute(CsvHelper.Configuration.Attributes.IndexAttribute, Assembly: CsvHelper) instead. [here](https://joshclose.github.io/CsvHelper/getting-started/)

```
public class Foo
{
    [Index(0)]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Index(1)]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```