# Why doesn't this property mapping result in the desired CSV column ordering?

Tags: c#, .net, csv, csvhelper

I've already tried [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49153840) but there is something wrong with my approach that the order assigned in the map is not being output in the CSV file.

```cs
public class Student
{
    public String Id { get; set; }
    public String Name { get; set; }
    public String Sport { get; set; }
    public String Risk { get; set; }
    public String Comment { get; set; }
}

public sealed class StudentMap : ClassMap<Student>
{
    public StudentMap()
    {
        Map(m => m.Id).Index(3);
        Map(m => m.Name).Index(1);
        Map(m => m.Sport).Index(2);
        Map(m => m.Risk).Index(0);
        Map(m => m.Comment).Index(4);
    }
}
```

```
List<Student> ListStudentFinal = new List<Student>();

using (var writer = new StreamWriter("output.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    csv.WriteField("OUTPUT TITLE TEST");
    csv.NextRecord();
    csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<StudentMap>();
    csv.WriteRecords(ListStudentFinal);
    csv.Flush();
}
```

The CSV output keeps writing like this:

```
Risk,Id,Name,Sport,Comment
```

Is there something wrong with this approach?  Or is there a different way I can test?

Comment: Do you get the desired results if you call `Map()` in the index order `0 1 2 3 4` instead of `3 1 2 0 4`?

Comment: @BACON when I check the map object, in the resultsview the map shows the same INCORRECT order, but the INDEX is the one I set in the mapping. Risk is shown at [0] with index 0 then Id [1] with index 3.

Comment: As an aside, I don't know if this is for debug purposes or not, but `writer.WriteLine("OUTPUT TITLE TEST");` might be a better way to force non-CSV text to the beginning of the file than `csv.WriteField("OUTPUT TITLE TEST"); csv.NextRecord();`, particularly since the latter could affect the state of the `CsvWriter` (even though it does work for me as-is).

Comment: @BACON it looks to be related with empty columns, I've changed the the order using columns which have data and the map index works, is there any config in the cvsconfig to prevent this happening?

Comment: Can you update the question with some sample data that produces the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I created a new .Net Core 3.1 console project, added CsvHelper (15.0.3), took your code verbatim and it worked.  With the header being:

```
Risk,Name,Sport,Id,Comment
```

This indicates some other issue or corruption in your project.  You may want to simply try creating a new project.  Or perhaps you are using an older version of CsvHelper that is behaving in a different way compared to the current release.

Comment: I'm running CsvHelper runtime v4.0.30319 version 15.0.0.0  with .NET 4.7.2

Comment: I recreated it again on Framework 4.7.2, but with the latest CsvHelper NuGet package, and it still works as expected.

Comment: I get the same order as this answer using the same framework, runtime, and package versions as @sys73r.  Unresolved question from GitHub: [CSV Member Order Incorrect using "Index(n).' method.](https://github.com/JoshClose/CsvHelper/issues/1340)

Answer (score 0):

Try registering your `ClassMap` before you write anything.

```cs
List<Student> ListStudentFinal = new List<Student>();

using (var writer = new StreamWriter("output.csv"))
using (var csv = new CsvWriter(writer, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture))
{
    csv.Configuration.RegisterClassMap<StudentMap>();
    csv.WriteField("OUTPUT TITLE TEST");
    csv.NextRecord();
    csv.WriteRecords(ListStudentFinal);
    csv.Flush();
}
```